# How to precache hashed files (/build/static) at the time of service worker installation using workbox in react application

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I have created a react application. I need make this application available offline for the user. To do that I have made it into a PWA using Workbox.

I am able to precache images but I also want to precache all the hashed files inside /build/static/js,/build/static/CSS and entire build folder at the time of service worker installation. Currently Workbox is caching all the images at the time of service worker registration, but the other js files are only cached once I visit the particular page. This means that only the sections of the application that the user visited while he was Online will be available when he goes Offline.

How can I cache all the hashed files and images at the time of service worker installation. Please suggest how I can achiev this.

Comment: Answered at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2458#issuecomment-614718973

Comment: Thank you Jeff Posnick. Will try this solution.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. It worked. One more thing I would like to ask is that the application works fine on google chrome but the install button doesn't comes up on firefox. Do I need to make additional settings for install button to appear on firefox(assets are there in cache)?